# Iterator on class member vector not correctly dereferenced

Tags: c++, iterator, stdvector

I am having a class called Domain, which has a protected member `std::vector` called
`itsVec`. The vector is accessible through `getVec()`.

In `main()` it works fine when I directly address the elements via
`getVec()[i]`. However, when I try using an iterator, the pointer to the first
element seems to not getting initialized correctly. Oddly, using an iterator on the `itsVec` in the class constructor works like a charm.

The code

```
#include<iostream>
#include <vector>

class Domain
{
  public:
    /* ====================  LIFECYCLE     ======================================= */
    Domain  ( ) {};                                    /* constructor        */
    Domain  ( unsigned int , const unsigned int * ) ;  /* custom constructor */
    Domain  ( const Domain &other );                   /* copy constructor   */
    ~Domain ( ) {};                                    /* destructor         */

    /* ====================  ACCESSORS     ======================================= */
    unsigned int              getDim() const {return itsDim;}
    std::vector<unsigned int> getVec() const {return itsVec;}

  protected:
    /* ====================  DATA MEMBERS  ======================================= */
    unsigned int              itsDim;
    std::vector<unsigned int> itsVec;

}; /* -----  end of class Domain  ----- */


Domain::Domain( unsigned int dim, const unsigned int  *externVec)
{
  itsDim = dim;

  for ( size_t j = 0; j < dim ; j++ )
    itsVec.push_back(externVec[j]);

  std::vector<unsigned int>::const_iterator i_vec  = itsVec.begin();

// iterator access works
  for ( ; i_vec != itsVec.end(); i_vec++) 
    std::cout<<"Iterator in constructor: " << (*i_vec) << std::endl;

  std::cout<<std::endl;

} /* -----  end of constructor  ----- */


/*-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
 *  Main
 *-----------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
int main ()
{
  const unsigned int kVec[3] = { 1, 2, 3 };

  Domain k(3,kVec);

  size_t i = 0;

// direct access works
  for( ; i<3 ; i++)
    std::cout << "Vec direct: " << k.getVec()[i] << std::endl;

  std::cout << std::endl;

// iterator access FAILS for the first element
  std::vector<unsigned int>::const_iterator  it_vec  = k.getVec().begin();

  for ( ; it_vec != k.getVec().end(); it_vec++) 
    std::cout<<"Vec iterator " << (*it_vec) << std::endl;

  return 0;
}       /* ----------  end of function main  ---------- */
```

Compiled with `g++ main.cc -o test` results in

```
$ ./test

Iterator in constructor: 1
Iterator in constructor: 2
Iterator in constructor: 3

Vec direct: 1
Vec direct: 2
Vec direct: 3

Vec iterator 140124160
Vec iterator 2
Vec iterator 3
```

Testing on another machine gave:

```
Vec iterator 0
Vec iterator 0
Vec iterator 3
```

Is the way I'm returning the vector through `getVec()` wrong. Is the
iterator handled incorrectly? I have no clue, whats wrong here or how to fix it.

Any help is highly appreciated,

Da Frenk

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are returning a copy of the vector rather than a reference and so you are not matching the iterators correctly. The iterator you obtain from `begin()` is from a different copy of your internal vector to the one you obtain from `end()`

Rather than returning a copy of the internal vector you can return a reference by changing the function prototype to:

```
const std::vector<unsigned int>& getVec() const {return itsVec;}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `getVec()` method returns the vector by value, which means that each time you call `getVec()` you get a new *copy* of the vector, so when you iterate, your `begin()` and `end()` iterators are incompatible. They belong to two different vectors.

You can fix this either by returning a reference to the vector:

```
const std::vector<unsigned int>& getVec() const {return itsVec;}
```

or extending your class to return the begin and end iterators of the vector.

```
class Domain
{
 public:
  std::vector<unsigned int>::iterator begin() { return itsVec.begin(); }
  std::vector<unsigned int>::iterator end()  { return itsVec.end(); }
  std::vector<unsigned int>::const_iterator begin() const  { return itsVec.begin(); }
  std::vector<unsigned int>::const_iterator end() const  { return itsVec.end(); }
  std::vector<unsigned int>::const_iterator cbegin() const  { return itsVec.begin(); }
  std::vector<unsigned int>::const_iterator cend() const  { return itsVec.end(); }
 // ... other methods
};
```

Comment: nice... a solution could be : `std::vector<unsigned int> vect =k.getVec(); std::vector<unsigned int>::const_iterator it_vec = vect().begin(); for ( ; it_vec != vect.end(); it_vec++) /...`

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response juanchopanza. Fixed the problem. @Hicham thanks for pointing out the syntax in main.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are returning a COPY of the vector, which gets discarded right away, leaving you with an iterator that doesn't point anywhere.

You probably want to return a reference, or a const reference.